# Is there a &&- and ||-operator in JSON instead of putting an array in a variable?

Tags: arrays, json

Is it possible in JSON to do this? Or is there just no function for that?

```
{
   Version: "4.3" && "4.4"
}
```

Instead of

```
{
   Version: ["4.3", "4.4"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON has no functions or operators at all. It's a structured data format, and no, there's nothing like what you describe. The array data structure is exactly like you show it: `[comma-seperated elements]`

Comment: Alright than, rip. This was the only other example I found, but there were no other examples...https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.json.doc/doc/r0061295.html